# Read dataframe from .png image

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ocr

I'm trying to create pandas data frame by reading data from the below image. But not able to read this data properly.

[image]

Below is my code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
```

```
img = cv2.imread('image.png') #table

# color conversion to gray scle image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# apply threshold
gray ,img_bin = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# change black background and white text
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(img_bin)
```

```
kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)

img = cv2.erode(gray,kernel,iterations=1)

img = cv2.dilate(img,kernel,iterations=1)

out_below = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

```
out_below

'foe jo 0 14\n° ey)\nee ec ac)\n2 entrepreneur 205 128\n3 housemaid 165 109\nTeme ED\nB Cy\nCe eG\nee)\n8 student 91 269\nCee\nCC ed\nee\n\x0c'
```

Any help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

May be **easyocr** will work for your case. you can install easy ocr by `pip install easyocr`.

```
import easyocr

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext('nOoPF.png')
for detection in result:
        print(detection)
```

the corresponding output is

```
([[13, 13], [61, 13], [61, 27], [13, 27]], 'deposit', 0.941881479602528)
([[125, 13], [147, 13], [147, 27], [125, 27]], 'job', 0.9999606319090059)
([[107, 41], [143, 41], [143, 53], [107, 53]], 'admin', 0.9929260014321377)
([[163, 39], [185, 39], [185, 53], [163, 53]], '703', 0.9999693038832459)
([[201, 39], [225, 39], [225, 53], [201, 53]], '631', 0.9999182357355408)
([[87, 65], [147, 65], [147, 79], [87, 79]], 'blue-collar', 0.8329462433551266)
([[157, 65], [187, 65], [187, 79], [157, 79]], '1236', 0.8340537244120172)
([[201, 65], [225, 65], [225, 79], [201, 79]], '708', 0.9350265356088533)
([[75, 91], [147, 91], [147, 107], [75, 107]], 'entrepreneur', 0.8589475594239738)
([[161, 91], [187, 91], [187, 105], [161, 105]], '205', 0.9999478992666728)
([[203, 91], [225, 91], [225, 105], [203, 105]], '123', 0.9999942186589443)
([[85, 117], [147, 117], [147, 131], [85, 131]], 'housemaid', 0.9998788796942103)
([[163, 117], [187, 117], [187, 131], [163, 131]], '165', 0.9945183441137533)
([[201, 117], [225, 117], [225, 131], [201, 131]], '109', 0.9676202212053554)
([[72, 142], [149, 142], [149, 160], [72, 160]], 'management', 0.9994768706140915)
([[157, 143], [187, 143], [187, 157], [157, 157]], '1265', 0.991637647151947)
([[195, 143], [225, 143], [225, 157], [195, 157]], '1301', 0.7132492339987888)
([[109, 169], [147, 169], [147, 183], [109, 183]], 'retired', 0.9999897720721911)
([[163, 169], [187, 169], [187, 183], [163, 183]], '262', 0.9972117114615124)
([[201, 169], [225, 169], [225, 183], [201, 183]], '516', 0.6857020258903503)
([[67, 195], [147, 195], [147, 211], [67, 211]], 'self-employed', 0.6106044244870804)
([[161, 195], [187, 195], [187, 211], [161, 211]], '218', 0.999991672117281)
([[201, 195], [223, 195], [223, 209], [201, 209]], '187', 0.9999954575173651)
([[99, 223], [147, 223], [147, 235], [99, 235]], 'semvices', 0.4017063882437147)
([[163, 221], [187, 221], [187, 235], [163, 235]], '554', 0.9999725386698679)
([[201, 221], [225, 221], [225, 235], [201, 235]], '369', 0.9950982075119915)
([[103, 247], [149, 247], [149, 261], [103, 261]], 'student', 0.6752341316623793)
([[201, 247], [225, 247], [225, 261], [201, 261]], '269', 0.9881978817220938)
([[89, 273], [147, 273], [147, 287], [89, 287]], 'technician', 0.9999779846433708)
([[161, 273], [187, 273], [187, 287], [161, 287]], '983', 0.9999987611408254)
([[201, 273], [225, 273], [225, 287], [201, 287]], '840', 0.9999931862770842)
([[76, 298], [147, 298], [147, 316], [76, 316]], 'unemployed', 0.9996709089085679)
([[163, 299], [185, 299], [185, 313], [163, 313]], '155', 0.9999801094525486)
([[201, 299], [225, 299], [225, 313], [201, 313]], '202', 0.9999910526883591)
([[95, 327], [147, 327], [147, 339], [95, 339]], 'unknown', 0.9982404795531601)
```

I hope this will helpful for you.